# Adding a connector to Kafka Connect

Tags: jar, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Confluent Kafka Docker image, specifically using this: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/4.0.x/examples/cp-all-in-one

I want to add the MySQL connector, by:

- downloading the version 1.5.46 of the connector (https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.tar.gz)
- mounting a volume with a jar that comes out of the downloaded connector (mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar)
- adding the `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` to the docker compose file

Basically, extrapolating the part of interest form the compose file, this is the important snippet:

```
environment:
  <cut>
  CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/etc/kafka-connect/jars/'
volumes:
  - "./mysql_connector:/etc/kafka-connect/jars/"
```

The JAR is correctly present in the Docker container.

But, of course, if I try to use the connector, I can't find in the list of the enabled connectors. If I go to control center, I see:

```
[{
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "1.0.0-cp1"
}, {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1.0.0-cp1"
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin path needs to contain the path to the actual JDBC Connect JAR files as well as the MySQL JAR

If you mount the MySQL JAR under this path

```
/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
```

Then set the `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java`, then you have access to all bundled connectors. And the JDBC Connector will be able to read/write MySQL data.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer.

Precisely, i have made the following (and i am contextually discovering that i made a mistake in my post):

1) mounted the jar folder in `/etc/kafka-connect/jars`

2) setup CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars/'

which should be equivalent, am i right ?

Comment: Note: Docker volume mounts can be single files. Doesn't need to be directories. That is why I suggested just mounting the JAR file.

Comment: So,

in the connect container i have the following jars:

`mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar` and  `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar`

And the CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH is: `/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect-mysql`

The `volumes` directory is:

    volumes:
      - "./connectors:/etc/kafka-connect-mysql"

And it worked ! I can select the connector via the control center `Kafka Connect` source list. Thanks a lot !